# jquery: how to check if a page is performing an ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to build a function that fires with every ajax request. Like showing "loading...". I am using Jquery is that possible?

Comment: You should show what you have tried here - some code for example as this IS doable but StackOverflow is not a consulting firm.

Comment: i think that my question doesn't need to show code because i m not facing a probleme in my code, besides do believe that s can be a technical question, may be you just didn't like it because it s a small question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible. Start with the global ajax handlers here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() events are the most likely candidate to show your status indicator.

Answer (score 9):

`jQuery.active` contains the number of active jQuery AJAX connections. However, you'd have to constantly poll that var in order to have an event fired in the advent of a new connection.

Anyway, why would you be using this for a "loading" indicator? Just set the indicator whenever you do the request.

Comment: great answer, this is what I looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

HTML:

```
<div id="loadingDiv">Loading ajax stuff...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#loadingDiv')
.hide() 
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As is said before, $.active contains the number of active jQuery AJAX connections. When the $.active reaches 0, all AJAX has been loaded. So, you can set a bucle and wait for all the executions. I found the solution here, "etgregor" answer

[How do I know if jQuery has an Ajax request pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending)