# How to know web page has been loaded completely using phantomjsdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Here, I am getting page content using `phantomjsdriver`. I am able to get the complete content of static web pages.
But,I am not able to get complete content of web pages having ajax calls(dynamic web-pages). When I try the below code 
I am able to get the content of dynamic web-pages. But I can't predict the loading time of page. So,I am looking for 
functions that tells page as been loaded completely.

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
 driver.get("http://www.blackwoods.com.au/search/flat-cut-off-wheels-metal-flexovit/302022874"); 
thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
driver.quit();
```

Here, I want to use function other then `thread.sleep(10000)`;.

Even I tried with below code. But didn't get the complete content

```
 WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
 driver.get("http://www.blackwoods.com.au/search/flat-cut-off-wheels-metal-  flexovit/302022874"); 
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ProductsPane")));
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Web Testing Box](https://github.com/ChonC/wtbox) and especially look at [WaitTool](https://github.com/ChonC/wtbox/blob/master/src/wtbox/util/WaitTool.java) which allows you to easily wait for elements to appear.

The tool for you is `waitForJavaScriptCondition()` which allows you to run a piece of JavaScript (in the context of the page under test).

You will then have to look at the framework which is used. If the page uses jQuery, for example, you can use `$.active != 0` as condition (see "[How do I know if jQuery has an Ajax request pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending)").

Comment: I have tried WaitTool
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 for following websites .But,there is no proper page content.
 http://ab.rockwellautomation.com/Circuit-and-Load-Protection/Circuit-Breakers/1489-Thermal-Magnetic#selection
 http://parts.arrow.com/Parametric/ParametricUI.jsp#base_pl=Amplifiers;rew4xP

Comment: My guess is that the site has anti-scraping protection. You'll have to analyze the JavaScript code and error log.