# How to detect ajax driven websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Here I Want to know webpage has AJAX calls or not. Because if webpage is AJAX based then I will wait for few seconds to get the web page contents, or else  if webpage is  not AJAX based then I will not wait .

I followed the below code but I didn't get any result.

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.get("http://www.airgas.com/category/Safety-Products-Clothing-WorkClothing-Acc/_/N-0Z84v");

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(event, request, settings) {
        alert("Web Page have Ajax Calls");
    });
});
);
```

If I use the jQuery code which I used in `javascriptexecutor` in developers console I am getting alert message stating that webpage has AJAX calls or not.
So is my approach is correct? If not what is the correct solution for my problem.

Comment: "So is my approach is correct..?" --- does it work for you?

Comment: This **[article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/testing-ajax-selenium)** might help you!!

Comment: @zerkms  . here jquery code is working if i put that one in developers console . . .  But i want same output using above code  . . There i am injecting javascript into selenium webdriver .

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're looking for this answer:
[How do I know if jQuery has an Ajax request pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending)

with the twist you'll need to give it first some time to execute and launch the requests and only then check if any active.
If any are active you can then wait till done.

HTH