# Ensure that JavaScript function gets called only if previous function finishes running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have this webpage, which when loaded runs a function (**loadListItems**) with some AJAX calls to populate a list with 10 items (there are multiple calls in a recursive matter, in order to get 10 VALID items).

There's a button on the page, which is visible at all times, and that button is there to load additional items in the list (the next 10 VALID items). The button calls **loadListItems** as well.

I want the button click to call the **loadListItems** function, however, if the previous call of the function is not finished, I want to queue the new call, so it runs whenever it finishes.

```
function pageLoad() {
   loadListItems();
}

var finished = false;
function loadListItems() {
   jQuery.ajax({
            url: ...
   }).done(function (data) {
      //do stuff with the data
      if (not enough data loaded) {
          //then call again recursively
          loadListItems();
      } else {
          //we're done
          var finished = true;
      }
    });
}

function buttonHandler() {
   if (finished) {
       loadListItems()
   } else {
       //run loadListItems whenever it finishes.
   }
}
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: Why not to disable a button until your ajax returns data on an error? Also, your question might be duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending

Comment: So do you want to queue up a new call for each time the button is pushed, or just have one queued up at any point?

Comment: Add an array of functions then loop through them when finished (or execute immediately if already finished).  Same as how jquery.document ready works.

Comment: As an aside, flooding your server with 10 requests to get data isn't very efficient and may have some unwanted performance related side-effects. If possible, I'd strongly suggest you combine the data from all the requests and send only one, then deal with the response as an array, if necessary.

Comment: The reason the code you have right now is not working is the line `var finished = true;`, which creates a new `finished` variable and sets it to true. You want `finished = true;` without the `var`, to set your global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, make a queue and call it after finishing.

```
function pageLoad() {
   loadListItems();
}

var finished = false;
// you may just increase or decrease a number 
// but in case you need to call it with parameters, use array
var queue = [];

function loadListItems() {
   // you need to set finish flag to false whenever you start call
   finish = false;
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: ...
   }).done(function (data) {
      //do stuff with the data
      if (not enough data loaded) {
          //then call again recursively
          loadListItems();
      } else {
          // check queue
          if(queue.length > 0) {
              var params = queue.shift();
              // call with params or not
              loadListItems();
          } else {
              finished = true;
          }
      }
   });
}

function buttonHandler() {
   if (finished) {
       loadListItems()
   } else {
       //run loadListItems whenever it finishes.
       queue.push([parameters to retrieve data]);
   }
}
```

This is what you want. But please check comments for better advise.
This is not the good solution.