# How to execute a javascript command multiple times with single line of code in browser console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I want to check if all ajax requests have completed and only then interact with element on a web page. Hence I opened chrome browser's developer console. And after entering url in search bar and hitting ENTER key, in console I keep hitting `$.active` multiple times and in results most of the time I can see returned value as `0` but some time as `1`

I hit `$.active` command with hand hence I am not able to see consistent result all the time. Is there any java script code which I can enter in console and after hitting it, `$.active` command will be hit one by one till the number of times mentioned?

Comment: Having a hard time finding out what `$.active` is, I don't see it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities) and it's hard to google, do you have a reference?

Comment: I got it from one of the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822913/how-do-i-know-if-jquery-has-an-ajax-request-pending

Comment: You're asking the wrong question (see here: [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)); what you want to do is run multiple asynchronous requests and run some code after all of them have finished. JS has `Promise.all` for that, and jQuery has [`.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) edit: are you saying the website (not you) is running those ajax requests, and you are simply trying to wait for them to finish?

Answer (score 0):

If `$` is jQuery, you can add an `ajaxComplete` callback, and check if `$.active` inside:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    if (!$.active) {
      console.log('All done');
    }
  });
});
```

It's not a single line of code, but it should work. (You can test it by running this in the console, then opening your inbox or reputation record in Stack Overflow's topbar. An ajax request will be sent out, and when it's complete, `ajaxComplete` will run, and `$.active` will get set to 0)

The `Promise.resolve().then` is needed because `$.active` gets decremented only *after* the `ajaxComplete` callback runs.